# Powershell / cmd does not render ssh programs run on remote machine

Tags: ssh, powershell, cmd.exe, remote

I can connect to my remote debian machine with ssh and all screen is drawn OK. Commands like build-ins or ping outputs seem to be rendered correctly. The problem starts when I like to do anything with nano or midnight commander. As a result I get powershell's plain background (blind typing exit works). I noticed the 'older version of console checkbox' allows me to display programs mentioned above but they are highly corrupted. SSH over cmd has the same issue.

Is there any way to repair this issue?

Or I have to start using third party terminals to render them correctly?

Edit for a clarification:
Windows 10 Powershell or cmd console:

*ssh user@host*

Access granted after pasword verification and I can execute everything like *ls, cd., users, ping* or execute my local *host* scripts with no problem. Everything as it should be.

When I start *nano* or *mc* Powershell (or cmd) window turns blank with its normal border color with no prompt, cursor, letters or semigraphics.
Keyboard works normally because I can exit from that blank window with usual ^C or typing exit and then all previous content of window is restored.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual ssh command that you're running and how you launch nano or MC inside the ssh session.

Comment: For reference, I am able to run `vi` and `nano` normally over ssh from cmd, powershell, pwsh, VS Code, and Windows Terminal. `ssh -V` shows `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1`.

Comment: mine just says Powershell returns: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019

Comment: Thanks Cpt.Whale. My local systems are W10 LTSB and W10 LTSC. Would anybody with PRO or HOME rise a voice? I just dont know if it is caused by my OS versions or windows at all.

Comment: It is all confusing righ now. Powershell itself, with no ssh connected to remote machine returns OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5.